# python bleach: inconsistent cleaning behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, bleach

I would like to use bleach to format some potentially unclean HTML.
In the following sample, ideally bleach should remove:

- the extra spaces in the first opening `<p   >`
- the attribute in the closing link tag `</a attr="test">`
- the extra spaces in the last closing `</p   >`

My code looks like this:

```
import bleach
html = """<p   >This <a href="book"> book </a attr="test"> will help you</p  >"""
html_cleaned = bleach.clean(html)

# html_cleaned is:
#'&lt;p  &gt;This <a href="book"> book </a> will help you&lt;/p&gt;'
```

As you can see, bleach is very inconsistent:

- the < and > of the opening and closing `p` tag are escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. For the link tag, this doesn't happen
- The spaces in `</p  >` are removed, in the opening `<p  >` they are not
- additionally, if I add an attribute to the closing `p` tag, `</p attr="test">`, it is not removed, while for the closing `</a attr="test">` the illegal attribute is removed.

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bleach.clean` expects an optional `tags` parameter which specifies allowed tags.
The `p` tag is not allowed by default and therefore doesn't get the sanitizing treatment.

My problem can be fixed by:

```
cleaned_doc = bleach.clean(input_doc, tags = bleach.sanitizer.ALLOWED_TAGS+["p"])
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any safety reasons as to why <p> is not allowed by default?

Comment: No, I was very surprised. <P> seems to be one of the most basic building blocks of html.